# Simple way of getting BoundingBox?

Tags: xna-4.0

I have looked on the internet and there is a few different ways but they don't seem to work for me. I have a Model called model1 and a matrix for it called maxtrix1, how do i get its min and max from these? Sorry for this question but it has been bugging me

Answer (score 0):

Are you calculating this bounding box each frame, what requirements do you have in terms of efficency and precission?

One way to this would be to apply the matrix to each mesh, then check the result of this multiplication against the previous multiplication if it is lower set it as the new minimum.. Finding the max values would be done in the same way, but instead check if its greater than the last one raither than smaller.

I might be able to help/elaborate more if you can explain why all the solutions you found on the interwebs didn't work for you :)